# Regular Expression in Bash (grouping)

Tags: regex, bash, regex-group

So here is what I have:

```
regex="^([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}[[:space:]])+[[:alnum:]]+$"
message="TEST-121 Testing" 
echo $message | grep -qE "$regex"
```

This works. However, I need something like below:

```
message="TEST-132 Testing is going on".
```

My current regex, return 1 and this should return 0. And the below one as well:

```
message+"TEST-111 TEST-132 Stack overflow rocks "
```

The above regex only suffices one word after the first string, so need help in updating [[:alnum:]] to something which can parse more words and not just one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the below regex should be fine:
`regex="^([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}[[:space:]])+([[:alnum:]][[:space:]]*)+$"`

Answer (score 1):

Add a `[:space:]` to the last character class as

```
$ regex="^([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}[[:space:]])+[[:alnum:][:space:]]+$"

$ message="TEST-132 Testing is going on" 
$ echo $message | grep -E "$regex"
TEST-132 Testing is going on

$ message="TEST-111 TEST-132 Stack overflow rocks "   
$ echo $message | grep -E "$regex"
TEST-111 TEST-132 Stack overflow rocks
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should wwork for all the input strings:

```
regex='^[A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}([[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]*)+$'
```

**Example:**

```
echo "TEST-111 TEST-132 Stack overflow rocks " | 
    grep -oE '^[A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}([[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]*)+$'
TEST-111 TEST-132 Stack overflow rocks
```